# How to iterate through json array in javascript that was returned by a rest service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, rest

I'm getting data back from a rest service and it looks like this:

```
(17) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Here is the code that gets and prints it:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/watchlist?name=My%20Portfolio", function(data) {
            watchlistIds = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(watchlistIds);
        });
    });
```

My goal is to loop through the objects in the array and output the symbol in each one.  If I open up the first object, it looks like this:

```
0:
watchlistId:
name: "My Portfolio"
symbol: "ABR"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I've made several attempts using different methods to loop through the objects, but nothing works. You can see some of the attempts here:

```
//                    $(watchlistIds).each(function(index,item) {
//                       watchlist = item[index];
//                       console.log(watchlist.symbol);
//                    })
//                    for (var i=0; i< watchlistIds.length; i++) {
//                        watchlistId = watchlistIds[i];
//                        console.log(watchlistId.symbol);
//                    }
                    symbols = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log("symbols="+symbols);
//                    for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
//                        data = symbols[i];
//                        console.log("data="+data);
//                        console.log(data.watchlistId.symbol);
//                    }
```

None of them work.  The uncommented one produces the following error:

> VM136811:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at
> position 1

Could one of you experts tell me what the right way to do it?

**EDIT**: I also tried this per commenter:

```
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/watchlist?name=My%20Portfolio", function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(item){
                console.log(item.symbol);
            })
         });
```

But this time the output was:

> undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any parsing at all when you use `$.getJSON`.

If all you want is to see each symbol try

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    // loop over array and log each one
    data.forEach(function(item){ console.log(item.watchlistId.symbol));
    //or to put in array of string values:
    const symbols = data.map(function(item){ return item.watchlistId.symbol})
    console.log(symbols)
})
```

If you want them in an array of just string values

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I added it to the EDIT section above.  Unfortunately, that didn't work either.  Output was "undefined"

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(item))` look like in the loop?

Comment: It looks like this: {"watchlistId":{"symbol":"ABR","name":"My Portfolio"}}
{"watchlistId":{"symbol":"ADBE","name":"My Portfolio"}}

Comment: Ahh ok...so you need `item.watchlistId.symbol`

Comment: Yes indeed, that worked!  Do you want to update your response so I can accept it, or should I just accept it now?